# Specific Columns shown in HTML table via Php and getcsv

Tags: php, csv, html-table

I'm just getting into php, html etc and am trying to resolve an issue at work. Please be patient with my lack of experience.

I have a csv file, TEST2.csv. it is as follows `advisor,guest,stockNumber,part,qty,partnote1,partnote2,status` that I am putting on a webpage so that our staff can select their advisor number and see the status of their parts. The report we export from our system is in csv and has columns that I do not want to show on this report. 
(before I hear I should learn another format to display this, I know, Im under a time constraint and need something quick and rudimentary for now)

Everything works well but it does not show column 7, only up to 4. I want it to skip 5,6 Here's the monster i've created:

```
<table id="demo">

<tbody>
<?php
$fp = fopen ( "TEST2.csv" , "r" );
    $wantedColumns = array(0,1,2,3,4,7);
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 1000 , "," )) !== FALSE ) {

    $i = 0;
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($data as $row) {
if (!in_array($i,$wantedColumns)) continue;
       echo "<td>" . $row . "</td>";
       $i++ ;
    }
    echo "/<tr>";
}
fclose ( $fp );
?>
```

`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `$i++` must be called __always__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using simple array syntax with `[index]` your code will be:

```
$fp = fopen ( "TEST2.csv" , "r" );
while (( $data = fgetcsv ( $fp , 1000 , "," )) !== FALSE ) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[2] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[3] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[4] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $data[7] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
fclose ( $fp );
```

Comment: Oh thank you thank you thank you. Once this is up I can start truly learning the full language, I'm just in a massive time constraint and have been fighting this for days. I tend to over think everything! You rock! I appreciate someone willing to help noobs like me get into it.